# How to pay taxes on earning from an inheritance without commingling it

Tags: united-states, taxes, inheritance

I am about to receive an inheritance that I would like to keep separate from my marital assets. The plan is to put it into a separate investment account in my name only. From my understanding, that will nominally prevent the inheritance from becoming commingled. What I don't understand is that the investments will hopefully make money and result in income tax liability. If I pay the tax out of marital assets, does that make the inheritance commingled? If so, how do I calculate the portion of the tax liability that I need to pay from the inheritance (and can long term losses on marital assets be used to offset tax on gains on the inheritance)?

Comment: Probably need a state on this, or least whether you're in a equitable distribution or community property state.